# Streaming file blocks event loop?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-rest

A project in micronaut 2.0.1 has a function to expose some resource.
The resource is streamed with an InputStream from another service by HTTP.

```
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
@Status(HttpStatus.OK)
@Get
public StreamedFile export() throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = service.getFromOtherServiceByHttpCall();
    return new StreamedFile(is, CSV_MEDIA_TYPE);    
}
```

Unfortunately, the app gets restarted because the health endpoint does not return quickly enough.

Is it possible that the `StreamedFile` blocks the event loop when returning file through the internet? Locally everything works.

---

Edit:

I think I found a solution for returning a string file, but unfortunately, it's considerably slower.

```
public Flux<String> export() throws FileNotFoundException {

    InputStream is = service.getFromOtherServiceByHttpCall();

    return Flux.using(() -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)).lines(),
            Flux::fromStream,
            BaseStream::close
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

I still don't understand how to properly stream a byte resource.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the event-loop thread may be your case even though this should not happen unless you are somehow spinning up only one single event-loop thread.

Nevertheless, you should be better piping the pulled file content to the `StreamedFile` on another separate thread using the `PipedOutputStream` / `PipedInputStream`:

```java
@Controller("/file")
public class FileHandlerController {

    private ExecutorService ioExecutor;
    private OtherService service;

    public FileHandlerController(@Named("io") ExecutorService executorService, OtherService service) {
        this.ioExecutor = executorService; // make sure to pipe on a separate thread so that the file gets returned immediately
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Status(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Get
    public StreamedFile export() throws FileNotFoundException {
        PipedOutputStream output = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream input = new PipedInputStream(output);
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            InputStream is = service.getFromOtherServiceByHttpCall();
            int b;
            while((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                output.write(b);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        });
        return new StreamedFile(input, CSV_MEDIA_TYPE);
    }
}
```